# Why hibernate raise StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when accessing a onetomany property?

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa

I have an Hibernate entity with a one to many propertiy. For this case, it has 16 elements in this property.

```
@Entity
Class Record {
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "record", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        public Set<Item> items;
}
```

When running, it raises StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when accessing this property like this:

```
if (record.items.size() == 0) {
    // record.item == null is fine.
    ...
}
```

However, if I set a break point at the `if` statement, then hit "resume", everything works fine, no exception will be raised.

I think perhaps hibernate has not finished loading the data yet and thus the exception during normal run. My question is whether this is the reason and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: My sincere apology for the wrong diagnosis of the problem. It is caused by a bug in the @PostLoad function. In this case, the question should be why it can run without exception when "break and resume".